# line of code is not initializing causing nullpointerexecption

Tags: java, android

I have a line of code that when I am debugging a nullpointerexception I can see that it is the cause of my app crashing.

The line of code that is causing the nullpointer is this:

```
ListView storeList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.storeList);
```

and then in debug mode it crash when it tries to assign this:

```
storeList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter2);
```

I do not know why the object is not initializing. The `ArrayAdapter` below it initializes fine. If you

Below is the actual java activity file:

```
public class StoreListView extends Activity {
UserFunctions userFunctions  = new UserFunctions();
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter2;
ArrayList<String> spinnerArray;



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ListView storeList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.storeList);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.storelistviewpage);
    arrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(StoreListView.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    spinnerArray = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("cusName");
    arrayAdapter2.addAll(spinnerArray);
    storeList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter2);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_screen, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

And below here is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/storeList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" >

</ListView>
```

Edit:
In case some are wondering I added the activity to the android mainfest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move

```
ListView storeList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.storeList);
```

after the `setContentView()` call.

Since your current code assigns the result of `findViewById()` *before* `setContentView()` is called, you will **always** get `storeList` being `null`, and so, you'll get an NPE.

Comment: That is perfect!!! I cannot believe it was that. I was thinking it was something else. Does everything have to come after those two lines in oncreate?

Comment: @Mark It's good practice since `findViewById()` returns the View you want, this can only happen if is there is a `contentView` set and that the `Id` you pass is valid. The only thing I can think of that needs to be before `setContentView()` is requesting window features.

Comment: @Mark if this answer has helped you, you should mark it as the accepted answer. If you have additional questions, your best bet would be to post another question.

Comment: sorry about that. It told me I had to come back in 15 minutes to accept it since you answered  it so fast.